# getting error when try to run PWA project on centos 7 server

Tags: magento, progressive-web-apps, magento2

When I am trying to run yard install then getting below error on centos 7 server.

```
postinstall-postinstall
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ENOTCONN
    at tryReadStart (node:net:662:20)
    at Socket._read (node:net:673:5)
    at Socket.Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:487:10)
    at Socket.read (node:net:729:39)
    at new Socket (node:net:449:12)
    at Object.Socket (node:net:318:41)
    at createSocket (node:internal/child_process:335:14)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:452:23)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
    at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:25732:24
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -107,
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

here are the versions
magento : 2.4.6-p3
node : v16.18.1
npm : 8.19.2
yarn : 1.22.19